SQLite Exception on .net MAUI : no such table: matches
I'm trying to create a counter for a card game, and I'm trying to store the "Matches" with the points on a Database. I have installed the nuget package sqlite-net-pcl, and I'm getting the error:

"no such table" even though I create the table through the CreateTable command.

The custom class about the DB:
using SQLite;

namespace Tichu_Counter
{
    public class DBManager
    {
        private const string db_name = "tichu_counter_db.db3";
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection dbconnection;

        public DBManager()
        {
        }
        
        static async Task Init()
        {
            if (dbconnection != null)
                return;
            dbconnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, db_name));
            await dbconnection.CreateTableAsync<Match>();
        }   
        public async Task<List<Match>> GetMatches()
        {
            await Init();
            return await dbconnection.Table<Match>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task  AddMatch(Match match)
        {
            await Init();
            await dbconnection.InsertAsync(match);
        }
        public async Task UpdateMatch(Match match)
        {
            await Init();
            await dbconnection.UpdateAsync(match);
        }
        public async Task DeleteMatch(Match match)
        {
            await Init();
            await dbconnection.DeleteAsync(match);
        }
    }
}

This is where I use it
        public MainPage()
        {
            dbManager = new DBManager();
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateMatch(); //Calling AddMatch()
            Load_Matches(); //Calling GetMatches()
            selectedindex = 0;
        }

These are properties
namespace Tichu_Counter
{
    [Table("matches")]
    public class Match
    {
        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        [Column("Match_ID")]
        public int match_ID { get; set; }

        [Column("Name_A")]
        public String name_A { get; set; }

        [Column("Name_B")]
        public String name_B { get; set; }

        [Column("Score_A")]
        public int score_A { get; set; }

        [Column("Score_B")]
        public int score_B { get; set; }

        [Column("Rounds_A")]
        public String rounds_a { get; set; }

        [Column("Rounds_B")]
        public String rounds_b { get; set; }

        [Column("Selected")]
        public bool selected { get; set; }

        [Column("Date")]
        public string date { get; set; }

I have tried using sync connection and still having the problem.

Can you help show the code of  CreateMatch(); and  Load_Matches(); to reproduce the  issue?

The error indicates that the command dbconnection.CreateTableAsync<Match>(); fails to create the needed table.
You can refer to the suggestions belwo on how to properly use Database on MAUI.

Install the SQLite NuGet packages:sqlite-net-pcl and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green

Configure app constants:



public static class Constants
{
    public const string DatabaseFilename = "tichu_counter_db.db3";

    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    public static string DatabasePath =>
        Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
}


Lazy initialization:


public class DBManager
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;
    public DBManager()
    {
    }
    async Task Init()
    {
        if (Database is not null)
            return;

        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Match>();
    }

For more details, you can refer to the official docs: .NET MAUI local databases.

Unfortunately it didn't help at all, I copy-pasted it, and still had the same issue

@NikolasG. Thanks for your update, I'll take a look and please help add the  CreateMatch();  &   Load_Matches(); in your post not comment.

Also, please help show the code in MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs.
